# How can an interactive script move multiple files from one directory to another?

Tags: bash, scripts

I'm trying to write a shell script that moves multiple files in a directory to another directory. I was able to write a script that asks the user what file they want to move and then moves that file to the target directory, but how can I move multiple files to another directory?

Here is the script I wrote for a user to move one file to another directory：

```
#! /bin/bash
echo " enter the name of the file that you want to move "
read filename
if [ -f "$filename" ]
then
 echo " enter the target directoy name that you want to move the file to"
 read dir
if [ -d "$dir" ]
then
 mv -i "$filename" "$dir" && echo "the file is moved to "$dir" successfully "
```

else
    echo "the directory is not found"
   fi
   else
   echo "the file is not found !"
   exit 1
   fi

Comment: Why do you need to write a script if a move operation is easily done by the mv command?

Comment: Plus this errors out on dirs not owned by the user :P

Comment: Please indent your code correct.

Answer (score 0):

This script loop over all files in current directory, and ask to move to specified directory:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e

read -p "enter the target directoy name:" -r dir
if [[ ! -d "$dir" ]];then
  echo "incorrect directory"
  exit 1
fi
if [[ ! -w "$dir" ]];then
  echo "directory is not writeable by current user"
  exit 1
fi

for filename in ./*; do
  [[ ! -w $filename ]] && echo "$filename cant be moved, access denied" && continue
  read -p "move $filename to directory? [y/Enter=No]" domove
  [[ ! -z "$domove" ]] && mv -i "$filename" "$dir" && echo "$filename moved successfully" || true
done
```